# What privileges do non-member observers of the United Nations have?

Tags: united-nations

It seems like they generally aren't allowed to vote on various issues, but they can voice their opinion on various issues if they please. Do they have any major powers in UN decision-making?

Comment: You are in the wrong place. Your question is about politics and not about law.

Comment: @Roland the privileges of UN delegates (voting and non-voting) are a matter of international law.

Comment: @Sneftel "but do they have any major powers in UN decision making" is a political question.

Comment: The question has answered itself: they cannot vote, they can voice their opinion. I don't see what legal question there is here.

Comment: @user6726: Poorly asked, perhaps, but WhyDenounce is new. And I see legal questions. "It *seems like* they generally aren't allowed to vote on various issues [Is this correct?]" "Do they have [de facto, under international law/UN Charter, as opposed to behind doors soft power] any "major" powers".

Comment: If they have no voting privileges and can only express their opinions why would you expect them to have any power?

Answer (score 3):

*Q: What privileges do non-member observers of the United Nations have?*

First, [as noted below](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/about-permanent-observers), "free access to most meetings and relevant documentation."

Second, as non-members, there are no membership fees assessed for their participation. The list, available through [A/INF/76/3/Rev.1](https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?ln=en&p=A%2FINF%2F76%2F3&f=&c=Resource%20Type&c=UN%20Bodies&sf=&so=d&rg=50&fti=0), shows "115 non-member States, entities and organizations having received a standing invitation to participate as observers in the sessions and the work of the General Assembly."

> Non-Member States of the United Nations, which are members of one or more specialized agencies, can apply for the status of Permanent Observer. The status of a Permanent Observer is based purely on practice, and there are no provisions for it in the United Nations Charter.

> Permanent Observers have free access to most meetings and relevant documentation.

*Q: Do they have any major powers in UN decision-making?*

Given "there are no provisions for [Permanent Observers] in the United Nations Charter," only the power to influence.